# JPQL all element of collection in collection query

Tags: jpa, jpql

I've a User class:

```
 @Entity
 public class User implements Serializable {
 //..
 @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 Set<UserPrivs> privs;
 //..
 }
```

where UserPrivs - enum.

I want to create method `List<User> getUsersByPrivs(Set<UserPrivs> privs)`, which will return all users containing all privs.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Like this using CriteriaBuilder?

```
List<User> getUsersByPrivs(Set<UserPrivs> privs) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
    final Root<User> u = cq.from(User.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    for (UserPrivs priv : privs) {
        predicates.add(u.join("privs").in(Arrays.asList(priv)));
    }
    cq.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select u from User u join u.privs p where p.name in :privsNames
```

This is any, to get all, you would need to join to the u.privs n times and AND them together.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
    String query = "select u from User u where 0=1 ";
    for (UserPrivs p : privs) {
        query += " or '" + p.name() + "' in u.privs";
    }
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! It's good variant, but can i do it on 'pure' JPQL?